# python: assign value to a variable whose name is stored in a variable

Tags: python, variables, assign

Maybe this question is very simple to answer, but after a long time of search in the internet I found badly no answer/workaround:

In Python (v3) I would like to do the following:

```
def func():
    pass

foo = "bar"

# Now I would like to make an assignment to a variable named
# based on the value of foo (i.e. effectively bar = func, but using foo)
# so that:
bar() == func()  # is True
bar is func  # is also True
```

How can I go about that?
Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: So you want to make a string callable, and then that callable be equal to the output of a function that doesn't output anything?

Comment: It is not possible to *"assign to an object"*. It seems like you want to write to the address of an object and thus overwrite it, as one could do in C. That cannot be done in Python. You can only assign values to variables (but that will not affect the object which was previously in that variable). To modify an object, that object should implement a method which would allow it. E.g. for lists, you can do `list1[:] = list2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing what the question is, but are you looking for something like this:

```
def func():
    pass

foo = "bar"
locals()[foo] = func

bar() == func() # True
# or better yet
bar is func # also True
```

Comment: If that was not the question, I can discard the answer. If it was, we can try to fix the question. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you very much! What vocabulary would you use for fixing the question?

Comment: I've proposed an edit to hopefully achieve that.